# Movie player has wrong activation state (1)

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk

Hi! I am capturing the thumbnail image of video from video url. And I am using following code to capture the thumbnail

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
UIImage *image = [moviePlayer  thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)1.0 timeOption: MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

I am using threading for this. I am getting the following error:

> Movie player has wrong activation state (1)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 13):

When you are `init`ing the movie player, you already have one.  There can be only one MPMoviePlayerController.   You are probably doing this in a loop.  You need to set your last one to `nil` or keep reusing the same one over and over.