# App crash in ios due to MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmoviewcontroller

[image: My Code]

In my Video Player App that plays online streaming videos.So i used

```
XCDYouTubeKit
```

This Plays Video with reference of MPMoviePlayerViewController.
When First Video is Playing and i clicked on other it gives me error and crash my app.

At line number 1094 i got the following error.

movie player MPMoviePlayerControllerNew: 0x13f0a1f10 has wrong activation state (1)

Comment: refer old [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041008/mpmovieplayercontroller-plays-only-when-called-twice-only-occurs-in-ios-4), it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you have more than one `MPMoviePlayerController` instantiated. You can play one video with  `MPMoviePlayerController` at once.

From Apple's doc,

> NOTE
>
> Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and
>   present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time
>   can play its movie.

source : [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is based on memory issue.

When you are `init`ing the movie player, you already have one. There can be only one MPMoviePlayerController. You are probably doing this in a loop. You need to set your last movie player object to nil or keep reusing the same one over and over.

Comment: Did you just copy pasted the answer from here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202777/movie-player-has-wrong-activation-state-1

Comment: yes ofcourse. I know that should rather point to that question by a link, But what if that link gets disabled or the question gets deleted? tats y i copied the answer.